# How to count with letters instead of numbers

Tags: python

What I want to do is count with a certain number of letters. the inputs will be n and x, where n is the number of letters to be used and x is the number I'm trying to count to. Say n is 3 and x is 12. It would go like this: 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab'. 'bab' is 12 when using 2 numbers to count. I know there is a mathematical way to do this, but I can't figure it out. Another test case is n = 16 and x = 248832. It would return 'clkop'. I'm sorry if someone has asked something like this before, I couldn't find anything. Also, let me know if this belongs on a different website. For clarity, the number of letters can range from 1 to 26. if it is 1, then 8 would be expressed as 'aaaaaaaa'. If the number of letters is 2, 8 would be expressed as 'aab'. If it is 3, then 17 would be expressed as 'abc' etc. I thought that it would be as simple as converting to base n, but it isn't. Hopefully, that helps. When I was writing this question, I saw a similar one that was in javascript, but it only did all 26 letters. I don't know how to convert javascript code into python code, and I want to be able to do any number of letters from 1-26. I know there is also a way to brute force this, but I don't know how

Let me know if the question needs more clarification

Edit: I figured out how to convert the string of letters into a number given the number of letters. For 16 letters, clkop = 3 * (16^4) + 12 * (16^3) + 11 * (16^2) + 15 * 16 + 16 = 248832 (or for an x length where v = the value of the current letter when iterating through the string, and n = number of letters, v * (n^x-1) + v * (n^x-2)... + v. Hopefully there is something you can do with that.

Comment: why you are using only 2 letters for n = 3?

Comment: So you want to print the combination indexed by `x`?

Comment: This wording and the first example of n = 3 are very confusing. The mathematical way you are looking for is called combinatorics. You can make these strings by backtracking which needs some average programming knowledge to execute correctly, or google combinations and permutations in python. If after googling how to do them for a good hour doesn't work, you can come back here with the code you wrote, its output and the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from string import ascii_lowercase

def alphabetic_counter(n, x):
    letterNums = [0]
    for i in range(x):
        yield ''.join(reversed([ascii_lowercase[l] for l in letterNums]))
        letterNums[0] += 1
        currIdx = 0
        while letterNums[currIdx] == n:
            if currIdx == len(letterNums) - 1:
                letterNums[currIdx] = 0
                letterNums.append(0)
            else:
                letterNums[currIdx] = 0
                currIdx += 1
                letterNums[currIdx] += 1
        
print(list(alphabetic_counter(2,12)))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab']
```

Not the prettiest solution, I have to admit, but either I have bad day for this sort of tasks or it is much harder than it looks on the first glance.

Comment: Yeah, this is supposed to be a hard problem that looks simple.

Answer (score 1):

You're basically asking how to convert a number into a different base, with the letters being the possible digits:

```
import string
namespace = string.ascii_lowercase
def convert(base, num):
  result = []
  while num:
    num -= 1
    num, mod = divmod(num, base)
    result.append(namespace[mod])
  return "".join(reversed(result))
```

Comment: It is not bases, because with 2 letters, aaa would be 0 in base 2, but with what I'm trying to do, it would be 7 (a, b, aa, ab, ba, bb, aaa)

Comment: The first `a` counts as a 1, the rest are 0s. You can easily add a yield to my solution and show the full count.

Answer (score 0):

With n different letters, we can form

[image: Eq 1]

different words of length at most k.
Solving for y yields that the yth word has length

[image: Eq 2].

If we start our count with 0 and the empty word '',  counting to x requires x+1 different words.

```
from math import log as ln
from math import ceil 
from itertools import  chain, product

def xth_word(x, n):
    '''returns  the xth word over the alphabet consisting of 
       the first n lowercase letters
       The empty word '' is the 0th word   
    '''
    letters = [chr(97 + i) for i in range(n)]
    word_length = ceil(ln((x + 1) * (n - 1) + 1) / ln(n)) 
    it = chain.from_iterable((product(letters, repeat=i)\
                              for i in range(word_length)))
    word = next(w for i,w in enumerate(it) if i == x)
    return ''.join(word) 

print([xth_word(i, 2) for  i in range(13)])
print(xth_word(248832, 16))
```

Output:
['', 'a', 'b', 'aa', 'ab', 'ba', 'bb', 'aaa', 'aab', 'aba', 'abb', 'baa', 'bab']
clkop